# Objects in Array C++ issue

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple game involving a Player class and have made an array to hold players when they've been instantiated. The problem is, every time I run the program, I get LNK 2019 errors-"unresolved external symbol". I am not sure why this is happening or how to get it working properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Player *player = new Player[9];
for(int i = 0; i< world1.numPlayers;i++) // ADD PLAYERS TO ARRAY
{
    Player tempplayer(3,3,5,1);
    player[i] = tempplayer;

}
```

This is the Player Class definition:

```
#pragma once
class Player
{
public:
Player(int width, int height, int xPos, int health );
~Player(void);
Player();
int getWidth();
int getHeight();
int getHealth();
int getPos();
void setHealth(int newHealth);
bool isAlive();
int width;
int height;
int health;
int xPos;

    };
```

Here is the exact warning: "Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Player::Player(void)" (??0Player@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\World.obj ConsoleApplicati‌​on2"

Comment: Have you provided definitions for each of your member functions, in particular the destructor?

Comment: The linker warning usually prints what it is unable to find. That is usually sufficient to pin point the source of error, or at least point in the right direction. Can you paste the complete warning?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You use of class pointers, instances and constructors seems kinda off.

This is what your code should look like:

```
Player *player[9];

for(int i = 0; i< world1.numPlayers;i++) // ADD PLAYERS TO ARRAY
{

    player[i] = new Player(3,3,5,1);

}
```

**EDIT:** Note that this only bypasses the cause of the original link error. The linker is complaining that the default constructor, `Player::Player(void)`, cannot be found. If I'm not mistaken, its being called when you create your array with `new Player[9]`. Declaring it should solve this error, allowing you to keep using the original code instead of my version.

Comment: 1) `player` is uninitialized here. 2) this will leak if `new Player` throws.

Comment: Forgot to add the index to the array, sorry. And yes, it will leak the previous elements if the constructor throws.

Comment: @MartínValdésdeLeón: The original loop was fine; yours adds _critical_ and _show-stopping_ bugs.

Comment: @MartínValdésdeLeón, thank you, that fixed the problem I was having. If I was to reference a Player object from the array, for example using the getHealth() method on player[0], would the following be correct?  player[0].getHealth();

Comment: No. `player[0]` would be a `Player *`, so you'd have to use `player[0]->getHealth();` or `(*player[0]).getHealth();`.

Comment: But please do listen to the others, and try the code you were using at the start. It was correct, and if it still doesn't work it means you have a bug somewhere that just hasn't come up yet. Check that you have the default constructor defined and declared. I was confused about C++ syntax when I first responded.

Comment: Thank You again. I apologize if I seem lost, I am learning C++ coming from Java so pointers are definitely new.

Answer (score 2):

Your array loop is fine.

The problem is that you didn't *define* in a `.cpp` file one or more of the class member functions that you've *declared* up there in your `.hpp` file.

We can't tell which one, because you didn't show the whole error, but ensure that they are all *defined*, even if only with empty definitions.

A common culprit is the destructor; when you don't need it to do anything, it's easy to forget to define it:

```
Player::~Player()
{
}
```

It may also be your default constructor:

```
Player::Player()
{
}
```

Define them all!

Answer (score 0):

Martin is right that you need to assign pointers to that array. I would have thought that such an error would have given you compile time warnings.

To the linker error - The linker warning usually prints what it is unable to find. That is usually sufficient to pin point the source of error, or at least point in the right direction. Can you paste the complete warning?

Usually the link time errors are a result of undefined member functions, as mentioned in the comment by dreamlax, OR failure to include one of the libraries.

Comment: `Martin is right that you need to assign pointers to that array. I would have thought that such an error would have given you compile time warnings.` The array and his use of it is absolutely fine.

Comment: Here is the exact warning: "Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Player::Player(void)" (??0Player@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\World.obj ConsoleApplication2"